# Magento 2.4.3 3rd level menu items on mobile devices using Porto theme

Tags: magento2, menu, mobile, porto-theme, mobile-menu

The appearance of the menu on mobile devices in Magento 2.4.3 using Porto theme is :

[image]

with the 3rd level menu expanded by default.

Is there a way to make the 3rd level menu collapsed by default? something like this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution on this page:
https://webguru.pt/how-to-make-magento-mobile-menu-collapse-on-all-levels/